# How to fix "Xaml parsing failed"?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, uwp

I'm using Visual Studio Enterprise 2017. When i try to run my UWP project on Mobile Emulator I'm getting "Xaml parse failed" error. 
When i run it on "local machine" everything is ok. I didn't make any changes to xaml header from the beginning. Can anyone help me?

Image showing error below.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdw78.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/KlrYz.jpg

```
<Page
    x:Class="KalkulatorBMI.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:KalkulatorBMI"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Grid Padding="10">
        <!--Padding - margines-->
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <!-- * zużywa co dostanie.-->
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0">
            <TextBlock Text="Trener persolany" Style="{ThemeResource CaptionTextBlockStyle}"/>
            <TextBlock Text="Użytkownik" Style="{ThemeResource HeaderTextBlockStyle}"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" >
            <ListBox Name="lbxUzytkownicy" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="150" Height="200" Margin="10" SelectedIndex="0"/>
            <Button Name="ButtonLoguj" Content="Loguj" Margin="10" Click="Click_Loguj"/>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="Nowy uzytkownik" Margin="10,0,0,5"/>
                <TextBox Name="TextboxNowy" Height="32" Width="138" Margin="10,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                <TextBlock Name="TextboxZlaNazwa" Margin="10,5,0,0" Foreground="Red"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                <Button Name="ButtonUtworz" Content="Dodaj użytkownika" Margin="10" Click="Click_Utworz"/>
                <Button Name="ButtonUsun" Content="Wyczyść listę" Margin="10" Click="Click_Usun"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="2">
            <Button Name="ButtonZakoncz" Margin="10" Content="Zakończ"  Click="Click_Zakoncz" Foreground="Red"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Comment: can you share exception details ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you need to check your app's target version & Min version first and make sure Mobile Emulator have this SDK version installed. if not, download if from [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/sdk-archive).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there are no other errors in any of your Style and ThemeResource definitions that aren't shown...

Remove the Padding="10" from the first Grid element (line#11?). Grid controls don't provide Padding properties.